# Mongoose : Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Some String" at path "_id"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

New to MongoDB, Javascript stack and need help understanding cause of this error.

I have my model created :

```
const
Mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = Mongoose.Schema,
Model = Mongoose.model;

module.exports = Model('Project',
    new Schema({
        icon    : String,
        name    : String,
        state   : String,
        number  :  String 
        
    })
);
```

This is my MongoDB document :

```
[![MongoDB Document][1]][1]
```

I am attempting to receive all the documents in the collection when I call the API so therefore as per the Mongoose document I am using the find() method.

Here is my API Implementation:

```
const Project = require('../../models/project');
router.get('/projects/:page?/:limit?',
    function(req, res, next){
      const page = Math.max(req.params.page || 1, 1) - 1;
      const limit = Math.max(req.params.limit || 20, 20);

//Verified : I am hitting the API      
console.log("Reached API /projects"); 
  

     Project.find()
           .populate('icon')
           .populate('name')
           .populate('state')
         .populate('number')
         .limit(limit).skip(page * limit).exec(
         function(err, project)
          {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
           res.send(project);
          }
        ); //End of exec()
     
    }//End of unction
  );
```

I am successful in making the API call using fetch() but I am receiving "Cast to ObjectId failed error" for all the String values.

I believe there is something really simple within my Mongo DB document that I might be missing. Please help me understand and solve this issue.

**EDIT ---

The error seems to point at the string values of the keys:
[image: Snapshot of the error]

**

Thank you

Comment: I don't think the error is caused by the provided code. Is there any code that's related to `_id`? for example `Project.findById(_id)` ?

Comment: @thammada.ts No I haven't used any findById(_id) methods . As I mentioned in my post, I am attempting to retrieve all the documents in the collection so I used only find() and not findById() or findOne().

Comment: Are there other documents with `_id` that doesn't have a hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId?

Answer (score 0):

Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s). So you're Id cast is not valid, because of string, you need to have ObjectId, some changes need to be made before it, Let's debug:

```
const alldata = await Project.find()
console.log(alldata) // ?
```

does this return something, I'm using `async await` here if it return data then the problem is with your populate because your Id case isn't valid as you save in schema `string` and you're referring here populate, example of using populate:

```
module.exports = Model('Project',
    new Schema({
        icon    : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'your icon document' }],
        name    : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'you name document' }],
        state   : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'state document' }],
        number  :  [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'number document' }] 
        
    })
);
```

but it seems to me that you don't need to use the populate because you have simple data, name, number... so you should be good to go with the above example

Resources: [mongoose fetching data](http://thecodebarbarian.com/how-find-works-in-mongoose.html), [using populate, relation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html)